# Undefined Instruction handler

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need to handle Undefined Instruction exception in my loadable kernel module.
So I use register_undef_hook(&my_undef_hook) in module initialization.
But I have such compile error:

```
...
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "register_undef_hook" [/home/user/my_driver.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "unregister_undef_hook" [/home/user/my_driver.ko] undefined!
...
```

I wonder, can I use these functions in kernel modules?

Comment: Which architecture?  Only avr32 and arm define this one.

Answer (score 0):

these functions are not exported (aka, there is no EXPORT_SYMBOL(register_undef_hook)) so they are not usable in modules code.

You have more details [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/linux-career-center/31161-the-kernel-newbie-corner-kernel-symbols-whats-available-to-your-module-what-isnt)

Comment: Ah. I see, thank you. But is any other way to trap exceptions is modules?

Comment: @AlexBoy, perhaps, [a "die notifier"](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=register_die_notifier) is worth looking at. This way, you can handle many kinds of exceptions. Not sure if it is available on ARM though.